# Responsive Jquery menu - when screen increased it works, but when decreased it doesn't

Tags: jquery, menu

I'm having trouble with a responsive menu: when the the browser size is bigger than 800 px it's a typical dropdown menu where submenus are opened by **hovering** ,but when the size is less than 800px submenus are opened by clicking (for mobiles).

The trouble is when I open page with 100% zoom it works fine (hovering), but when I zoom in ( less than 800px) then I have doubled effect: hover works and clicking too. How to "turn off" hover effect and have clicking only. 
Hopefully this code explains everything:

```
function checkResize() {
    var ww = $(window).width();
    if ( ww < 800) {
        $('#main-menu-list li').on('click', function() {
            if ($(this).length>0) {
                $(this).children('ul').toggle();
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#main-menu-list li').hover(function() {
                $(this).children('ul').fadeIn();
            },  
            function() {
                $(this).children('ul').fadeOut(200);
            }
        );
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `checkResize` method is invoked multiple times, you should remove the event listeners before adding new ones. For example remove all `click`, `mouseenter` (hover in) and `mouseleave` (hover out) listeners:

```
function checkResize() {
    $('#main-menu-list li').off('click mouseenter mouseleave');
    ...
```

This should leave you with either click or hover behaviour.

Comment: Thank You very much, I just added that one line .off(..) - and it's working perfect now!